# What is difference between chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted and chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener with 'complete'

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In chrome APIs there are two functions that theoretically points to the same evet.

`chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted` and  `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener` with `changeinfo=complete`.

What is the difference between these two and which one guarantee that everthing in the page have loaded. I have found that `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener` sometimes fire even when few http requests are remaining.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted` is invoked even when the navigation occurs in a subframe whereas the `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener` is only triggered when a tab is updated due to change in a tab's property like `status` or `url`. Observe the changeInfo object that is passed to the callback function [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated).

Also, the `chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted` supports filtered events, thus you can specify the filter so that the event is triggered only when the filter is passed. Observe [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events#filtered) how to apply filters to an event.

So, if you use both the event listeners, you will observer that the `chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted` is fired many a times for a single tab whereas the `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener` might fire only once or twice (due to status change from loading to complete).

I hope this helps.