# chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted - Event firing multiple times

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I load plagin for Inject code to page, the manifest code:

```
{
  "name": "any",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "webNavigation",
    "*://*/*" 
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

And the background.js:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function(details) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(details.tabId, {
        code: 'console.log("A")'
    });
});
```

The problem is the event firing a few times after page load, I want the event just one time. What is my mistake?
I would appreciate any help on.

Comment: I think you may switch to use chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener rather than this. Because the chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted is invoked even when the navigation occurs in a subframe whereas the chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener is only triggered when a tab is updated due to change in a tab's property like status or url. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35030705/what-is-difference-between-chrome-webnavigation-oncompleted-and-chrome-tabs-onup

Comment: But if you still want to go with chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted, you may need to add filter https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events#filtered

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried the tabs.onUpdated and the event was  firing four times on each page, whether it is possible to limit it only once?

Comment: I searched in the list of filters available for WebNavigation, and I dont found a filter that can be compatible, you can refer me to the relevant filter?

Comment: chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {          
 alert(changeInfo.status);
 if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {  }
});

Comment: it's wonderful! Thank you! you helped me alot!

Comment: Glad this helps :)

Comment: `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => { 
            if (changeInfo.status == 'complete' && tabId == params.tab.id) {
                console.log('COMPLETED:', params.tab.url, changeInfo);
                resolve(params);
            }
        });` still fires twice for me :-(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted is invoked even when the navigation occurs in a subframe. One way to capture it only once is to implement your code with a condition for frame id. frame id = 0 corresponds to the parent frame. Your code would look like :

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function(tab) {
    if(tab.frameId==0){
    //logic
    }
});
```

detailed documentation available here : https://developers.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to use ***named functions***, register them when ready and, on the performance point of view, only for the requested URLs (if possible).
in the next example the listener is getting removed before registered plus only if the filter contains URLs:

```
if (filter.url.length < 1) {
    resolve(dictionary);
    return;
}

if (chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.hasListener(onBeforeNavigate))
    chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.removeListener(onBeforeNavigate);
chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener(onBeforeNavigate, filter);
```

and the named should follow this pattern:

```
const onBeforeNavigate = (details) => {
    if (details.frameId > 0)
        return;
...
}
```

see more info here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webNavigation/onCompleted